# Setting a composite foreign key to NULL in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, `parents` and `children`, and a column in `children` called `parent`. I also have a column called `account_id` in both tables that should be `NOT NULL`.

I also have a composite foreign key like this:

```
ALTER TABLE children
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS parent UUID,
    ADD CONSTRAINT parent_id FOREIGN KEY (account_id, parent) REFERENCES parents(account_id, id)
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Upon deleting a row from `parents`, I want the child to remain in the `children` table, but with a `parent` of `NULL`. However, the above migration causes an error in the case of a delete, complaining that the value of `account_id` cannot be `NULL`. How can I rewrite my constraint to achieve this?

Comment: Achieve what? Do you want to set a column defined as NOT NULL to NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with `ON DELETE SET NULL`. You will have to define a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on `parents` that sets `parent` on the referencing rows in `children` to NULL.